# How do store values from a text file in an array in Java?

Tags: java

I am really struggling with this assignment in class.  We are making a sudoku program that takes in a text file with info like this:

```
. . .   9 . 2   6 . 4
6 . 4   3 . .   . 7 .
. 7 .   1 . 4   . . .

. . 3   . 1 9   8 . .
1 5 .   . 4 .   . 9 7
. . 7   8 2 .   3 . .

. . .   2 . 6   . 5 .
. 3 .   . . 7   1 . 2
9 . 2   5 . 1   . . .
```

and returns a text file with the correct sudoku answer.  Now, I have not even started on the backtracking algorithms needed to do this.  All I need help with is getting the info from the text file I showed you and store the info in such a way that I can apply those backtracking algorithms to the data received from the text file.

I wrote code to read and display (for testing purposes) the text file, which is this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.IOException;

public class SudokuSolver {

```
   int [][] sudoku;

   SudokuSolver(){
       sudoku = new int[9][9]; 
   }

   public void readinFile(){
       //SudokuSolver su = new SudokuSolver();
       System.out.println("Reading File from Java code");
       //Name of the file
       String fileName="C:\\puzzle1.txt";
       try{

       //Create object of FileReader
       FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);

       //Instantiate the BufferedReader Class
       BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

       //Variable to hold the one line data
       String line;

       // Read file line by line and print on the console
       while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)   {

               System.out.println(line);
       }

       //Close the buffer reader
       bufferReader.close();

       }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line:" 
               + e.getMessage());                      
       }

       }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       SudokuSolver s = new SudokuSolver();
       s.readinFile();
   }
```

But all this does is read the text file.  My question is this:  How can I extract the info needed for the computer to solve the sudoku problem?  I need both the numbers and the '.' (as the '.' are needed to tell the computer it is an empty space) but not the spaces from the text file.  I've tried looking this up on the internet but it is hard for me to understand as this part (reading in parts from a text file) was not covered in class at all.  Any help would be appreciated!!!  Thank you!

Comment: [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing Java, your #1 resource is always going to be the Javadoc. Looking at the [Javadoc for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) you'll find many methods for manipulating / extracting the contained data.

You have a number of options. I'll offer two:

1) Iterate through the `String` and pick out the non-whitespace characters.

You can achieve this with a loop:

```
for (char c : line.toCharArray()) 
{ 
    // check each character, convert to `int`, put in your array
}
```

2) Use the `.split()` method which will return a `String[]`.

`.split()` takes a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). By supplying a regex that says "Split on one or more spaces" you'll get back each number and . as a `String`:

```
String[] elements = line.split("\\s+");

for (String s : elements) 
{
    // convert to `int`, put in your array
}
```

Note that you're going to also have to decide how to represent `.` in your `int[][]`. Perhaps use `-1`.

Comment: I will try what you suggested.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Loads of options.  I like regex, so how about this:

```
/** Describe a sudoku line. */
private static final Pattern SUDOKU_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\s*([\.\d])\s*([\.\d])\s*([\.\d])\s*([\.\d])\s*([\.\d])\s*([\.\d])\s*([\.\d])\s*([\.\d])\s*([\.\d]).*");
private static final int CELL_COUNT = 0;

public List<Chararcter> parseLine(String line) {
  Matcher m = SUDOKU_PATTERN.matcher(line);
  List<Character> parsedLine = new ArrayList<Character>(9);
  int index = 0;
  while (i < CELL_COUNT) {
    parsedLine.add(m.group(i++));
  }
  return parsedLine;
}
```

Obviously, lots of error handling is required.  I think you could also use a non-capturing group around `\s*([\.\d])` followed by a possessive quantifier, to make the pattern simpler.  The returned `List<Character>` is the ordered sequence of digits and dots from the input line.  Further code to parse into numbers is an exercise left for the person with the homework.